# Bootstrap btn class, but not hover state

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there is **.btn** class in bootstrap

```
<span class="btn" style="background-color: #82CFFD"><strong>R</strong></span>
```

It has nice styling, but is reacting like button, hover state etc, etc.
Is there in bootstrap class like .btn but not to have hover state, or we have to make it :(

Comment: why dot you disable / comment out the hover state with in your css file or have your css overwrite this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to add some `.nohover` class to the desired `.btn` elements that would have the same styles as a `.btn` class

HTML

```
<span class="btn nohover" style="background-color: #82CFFD"><strong>R</strong></span>
```

CSS

```
.btn.nohover:hover {
    /* here copy default .btn class styles */
    cursor:default !important;
    /* or something like that */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The way to achieve what you want is to set your [button style](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options), something like `btn-default`, and then add the [`active` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-active):

```
<span class="btn btn-default active" style="background-color: #82CFFD"><strong>R</strong></span>
```

The only caveat is that the button will always look "pressed." If you don't want the button to look pressed, you'll have to make a custom override.

Comment: Instead of **active** try **hover** instead

Answer (score 1):

If you set styles with the attribute `style`, than this will top all styles set from a css file for the class `.btn`. So you will not get a hover state style defined in bootstrap css.

And since boostrap 3 you have to set a css base class `btn` and a modifier class `btn-default` or `btn-primary` or ...

Answer (score 1):

```
.btn:hover {
  color: @grayDark;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: darken(@white, 10%);
  background-position: 0 -15px;

  // transition is only when going to hover, otherwise the background
  // behind the gradient (there for IE<=9 fallback) gets mismatched
  .transition(background-position .1s linear);
}
```

you can use hover like this,

and if you want knowledge about bootstrap and it's functionality, refer this link,

http://jacobrask.github.io/styledocco/styledocco/examples/bootstrap/docs/buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<a href="#" class="btn" role="button"><strong>R</strong></a>
```

you have to make an override of the class .btn from bootstrap

```
.btn:hover {
  background-color : 'your background color';
}
```

for the cursor there is an example :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=default

Comment: I dont want to react like a href, only to not have hover state and cursor pointer no :)

Comment: there is an example for you :
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=default

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sass ( .scss ) you can simply overwrite the style.. I suggest you wrap this in another unique div though, so you don't inadvertently effect ALL .btn classes for future use.

```
.btn {
  &:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there is a simple way you can achieve this in bootstrap only.

```
<span class="btn btn-default bg-light text-dark border border-secondary"><strong>R</strong></span>
```

You can change border-secondary for the other colors: border-primary, border-success, etc.

And so you can do that to the bg-light as well.

Text color is done with: text-white, text-dark or the other bootstrap text colors.

if you want to use a different background-color than bootstrap use: style="background-color: #82CFFD"

```
<span class="btn btn-default border border-secondary" style="background-color: #82CFFD"><strong>R</strong></span>
```